# Problems with scopes or closures

Tags: javascript, service, scope, closures, this

#### Problem:

I have a very simple snippet of code.
I create and object with a member variable "counter" and a member function "start()" which increases the counter variable by 1 every second.
The problem here is that the counter variable does not increase when start() acts on it.
This has been driving my head crazy.

#### Hypothesis:

I believe this is a problem with the "this" keyword or a scope/closure issue but I'm not sure what's exactly wrong.

#### Code:

```
var livePlayer = {
        counter : 0,
        liveIteration: null,

        start: function(){
            this.liveIteration = setInterval(this.incCounter, 1000);
        },

        incCounter: function(){
            this.counter++;
            alert(this.counter); <-- this should return 0, 1, 2, etc. but returns NAN instead
        }
    };

livePlayer.start();
```

#### JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/justinwong12337/1wjdr0dh/

Your help is greatly appreciated!

#### Additional info:

This object and its members are part of an AngularJS service and are to be used by a separate controller file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is neither with scope or closures. :-) It's with `this`, which is a slippery concept in JavaScript.

In JavaScript, `this` during a function call is set almost entirely by **how** the function is called, not where the function is defined. It's basically a special form of function argument. (This is quite different to its meaning in other languages with similar syntax.) The particular problem in your case is here:

```
this.liveIteration = setInterval(this.incCounter, 1000);
```

When the browser's timer code calls your `incCounter`, it will do so with `this` set to the global object, not to *your* object. So `this.counter` isn't the `counter` property on your object (because `this` doesn't refer to your object), and things don't work as expected.

You can solve this several ways, probably the most direct is ES5's `Function#bind` (which can be shimmed on older browsers):

```
this.liveIteration = setInterval(this.incCounter.bind(this), 1000);
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, calls the original function with `this` set to the first argument you give it.

More to explore *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and simple answer!
The bind function works like magic!

Comment: Another solution I stumbled upon was replacing any instance of "this" with the object name ("livePlayer") instead.

So for instance, 
livePlayer.liveIteration = setInterval(livePlayer.incCounter, 1000)

Comment: @justinSYDE: Yes, because your `livePlayer` object is a singleton, that's just fine as well. In fact, for a singleton, I'd say it's probably better. The above is for when you may have more than one object sharing the same code.